# How to write this non-constructive proof in Lean?

Tags: lean, lean3, lean-mathlib, classical-logic, proof-techniques

There is a theorem which says that there exists two irrationals $x, y$ such that $x^y$ is rational.

An interesting proof in classical logic is the following:

> Consider $u = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$.
> If $u$ is rational then we use $(x,y) = (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.
> Otherwise, we notice that $u^\sqrt{2} = 2$ and use $(x,y) = (u,\sqrt{2})$.

I'd like to implement that proof in Lean (3) (the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ is already proven in mathlib).

I managed to write a signature of my theorem ([execute](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=import%20data.real.irrational%0Aimport%20analysis.special_functions.pow.real%0A%0Aopen%20classical%0A%0Atheorem%20classical_logic_existence%20%3A%20%E2%88%83%20x%20y%20%3A%20%E2%84%9D%2C%20irrational%20x%20%E2%88%A7%20irrational%20y%20%E2%88%A7%20%C2%AC%20%28irrational%20%28x.rpow%20y%29%29%20%3A%3D%0Asorry)):

```
import data.real.irrational
import analysis.special_functions.pow.real

open classical

theorem classical_logic_existence : ∃ x y : ℝ, irrational x ∧ irrational y ∧ ¬ (irrational (x.rpow y)) :=
sorry
```

My questions are:

- How can I use `x^y` instead of `(x.rpow y)`? (just replacing it produces an error)
- How would I implement my proof in Lean? I have no idea how to write the case disjunction and so on...

Comment: First of all I strongly suggest you to move to Lean4 (for this kind of question the answer is essentially the same, and Lean3 is end of life). The `^` is just notation introduced somewhere, try to import a less basic file and you should get it. Concerning the real question, have you read [TPIL](https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/) or any other basic reference?

Comment: @Ricky the default online interpreter on Lean's website is running on Lean 3. Do they also provide one on Lean 4?

Comment: [Here](https://lean.math.hhu.de/)

Comment: A fine exercise in Lean, but a poor demonstration of excluded middle: $(\sqrt{2})^{\log_2 9} = \sqrt{2^{\log_2 9}} = \sqrt{9} = 3$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer or $e^{\ln(2)}$

Comment: Showing that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\log_2 9$ are irrational requires just some basic number theory. If I remember correctly, showing that $e$ is irrational is significantly more work. And it's even more work to show that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational (which is why the use of excluded middle is not entirely superfluous, as it allows us to trade ignorance for hard work).

Comment: @Ricky (or anyone else): Regarding my initial question, I find it disconcerting that I'm struggling to prove
`lemma simple_lemma: ((sqrt 2) ^ (sqrt 2)) ^ (sqrt 2) = 2`

Shouldn't `simp` be able to solve it? How would you proceed?

Comment: Just use [pow_mul](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/group_power/basic.html#pow_mul) and [pow_two](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/group_power/basic.html#pow_two), (both backwards), then `simp` can probably do it. I don't see why `simp` should do it automatically, it's easy, but there is no reason to have [pow_two](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/algebra/group_power/basic.html#pow_two) as a `simp` lemma.

Comment: @Ricky Thanks, I proved the lemma. Now my goal is `¬irrational 2` and I don't even know how to prove this... seems like 2 is considered as a real and `rw nat.not_irrational(2)` won't do it.

Comment: You should  ask for help on zulip.

Comment: I eventually managed to find an example and make my proof work. I will answer my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I eventually managed to write a proof (execute [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=import%20data.real.irrational%0Aimport%20data.rat.sqrt%0Aimport%20analysis.special_functions.pow.real%0A%0Aopen%20real%0A%0Alemma%20simple_lemma%3A%20%28%28sqrt%202%29%5E%28sqrt%202%29%29%5E%28sqrt%202%29%20%3D%202%20%3A%3D%0Abegin%0A%20%20rw%20%3C-rpow_mul%2C%0A%20%20rw%20%3C-pow_two%2C%0A%20%20by%20simp%2C%0A%20%20simp%20%5Bsqrt_nonneg%5D%2C%0Aend%0A%0A%23print%20simple_lemma%0A%0Atheorem%20existence_theorem%3A%0A%20%20%E2%88%83%20x%20y%20%3A%20%E2%84%9D%2C%20%28irrational%20x%29%20%E2%88%A7%20%28irrational%20y%29%20%E2%88%A7%20%C2%AC%28irrational%20%28x%5Ey%29%29%20%3A%3D%0Abegin%0A%20%20--%20Technicality%3A%20we%20need%20to%20prove%20that%202%20%28as%20a%20real%29%20is%20not%20irrational%0A%20%20have%20not_irrat_2%20%3A%20%C2%AC%28irrational%202%29%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20convert%20rat.not_irrational%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20norm_cast%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20by_cases%20h%20%3A%20irrational%20%28%28sqrt%202%29%5E%28sqrt%202%29%29%2C%0A%20%20--%20h%20%3A%20irrational%20%28sqrt%202%20%5E%20sqrt%202%29%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20existsi%20%5B%28sqrt%202%29%5E%28sqrt%202%29%2C%20sqrt%202%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20simp%20%5Bh%2C%20simple_lemma%2C%20irrational_sqrt_two%2C%20not_irrat_2%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20--%20h%20%3A%20%C2%ACirrational%20%28sqrt%202%20%5E%20sqrt%202%29%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20existsi%20%5Bsqrt%202%2C%20sqrt%202%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20simp%20%5Bh%2C%20irrational_sqrt_two%5D%2C%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0Aend%0A%0A%23print%20existence_theorem)).

What I was looking for was essentially the tactic `by_cases` for cases disjunction.

It is also longer than I expected because I couldn't fully automate proving things like `((sqrt 2)^(sqrt 2))^(sqrt 2) = 2` or `¬(irrational 2)`.

*Note that, as pointed out in a comment, this proof is in Lean 3 and it is preferable to use Lean 4 as of today.*

```
import data.real.irrational
import data.rat.sqrt
import analysis.special_functions.pow.real

open real

lemma simple_lemma: ((sqrt 2)^(sqrt 2))^(sqrt 2) = 2 :=
begin
  rw <-rpow_mul,
  rw <-pow_two,
  by simp,
  simp [sqrt_nonneg],
end

theorem existence_theorem:
  ∃ x y : ℝ, (irrational x) ∧ (irrational y) ∧ ¬(irrational (x^y)) :=
begin
  -- Technicality: we need to prove that 2 (as a real) is not irrational
  have not_irrat_2 : ¬(irrational 2),
  {
    convert rat.not_irrational 2,
    norm_cast,
  },
  by_cases h : irrational ((sqrt 2)^(sqrt 2)),
  -- h : irrational (sqrt 2 ^ sqrt 2)
  {
    existsi [(sqrt 2)^(sqrt 2), sqrt 2],
    simp [h, simple_lemma, irrational_sqrt_two, not_irrat_2],
  },
  -- h : ¬irrational (sqrt 2 ^ sqrt 2)
  {
    existsi [sqrt 2, sqrt 2],
    simp [h, irrational_sqrt_two],
  },
end
```